# Book like “l’étranger” in French

Tags: ressources, littérature

I read this French book during the summer and I loved it, and at the end of Assimil’s Using French, I’m looking at a place where I can start to dive into French literature. Is there anything like *L’étranger* by Camus out there? I’d like the book in original French. 
I enjoyed the character and the shock, which Jean-Paul Sartre calls it, and the sense of absurdity and the customs of our main character who seemed to us a stranger, as we only knew him through these customs, and we never knew much more about him except his thoughts and actions.

Comment: Other books by Camus? :)

Comment: What does it mean to be like 'L'étranger' ? I know the book but anyone could hardly tell you much more than to go for other books by Camus because your question is too vague. If that's of any help, I used to read Romain Gary / Émile Ajar and Réjean Ducharme when I was into Camus.

Comment: I’m not actually sure what I meant. I was wanting to read Les Misérables but that seems too advanced at the moment, and I’m not sure how I should approach reading French literature, as besides my textbooks, I haven’t read much foreign literature by itself.

Comment: @ThatLanguageGuy If you liked _L'étranger_, you may like _Thérese Raquin_ by Emile Zola.

Comment: Maybe tell us what you liked in L'étranger and what you didn't like

Comment: @TeleportingGoat The absurdity which is present in the novel almost made us know Meursault through his thoughts which were sometimes contradictory to morals that humans have, and it made it a sort of mystery to us and made the character of Meursault sort of a character. The sort of shock, as Jean-Paul Sartre describes it, which is felt when opening the book, just sort of makes the whole story strange and of course the main character is made a stranger.

Comment: You should add that bit to your question so people don't have to dig comments to see it :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I added it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in French literature, you may read some classics like *Les Fleurs du Mal* by Baudelaire, or *Germinal* by Émile Zola, or *Les Misérables* by Victor Hugo. These books are classical books that most of French people read before. Perhaps it's a bit difficult if you started reading French literature. 
There is a lot of new vocabulary (if you are an English guy who wants to learn new words).
Perhaps you need to make a list of what type of French books you want to read, because the language was different during the 18th - 19th century.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try reading some plays? Camus wrote some plays--*Caligula* and Le Malentendu, for example--and jean-Paul Sartre wrote a lots of plays. I would suggest beginning with *Huis clos*, which is fairly short, but there are many others. In fact the 20th century is full of wonderful French playwrights. This is how I found my way into reading French and into French literature. It's frankly easier, all else being equal, to finish a play than a novel (with some exceptions), and finishing a play gives you a sense of accomplishment. This  modest beginning lead to a career in teaching French. D’ailleurs je m’excuse de ne pas vous écrire en français.

Comment: Merci ! Ne vous en faites pas, je lirai n’importe quelle réponse soit en anglais ou en français. D’ailleurs, je dois probablement mentionner que j’ai acheté un œuvre de Jean Paul Sartre qui s’appelle “la nausée” et puis j’ai aussi remarqué que les lettres de Camus étaient tellement simples pour commencer aussi. (Je m’excuse d’avoir probablement fait plein d’erreurs dans ce commentaire) et je ferai une recherche en ligne pour feuilleter les pièces de Camus que vous avez mentionnées

Answer (score 2):

*L’étranger* est un roman court, écrit avec des phrases simples, d’une grande portée philosophique, et très très connu.

Pour quelqu’un qui cherche à aborder la langue française par la littérature francophone, ce sont là quatre qualités qui rendent ce roman très intéressant : la brièveté permet de toucher rapidement à différents auteurs et styles; la simplicité ne décourage pas le nouveau-venu; la portée philosophique stimule le lecteur adulte; la popularité permet de rapidement pouvoir trouver quelqu’un avec qui en discuter.

Afin de diversifier l’expérience, je chercherais un auteur autre que Camus pour continuer.

*Le petit prince* d’Antoine de Saint-Exupéry est un autre roman, d’un style assez différent à *L’étranger,* mais possédant lui aussi ces quatre qualités de brièveté, simplicité, portée et immense popularité. On ne saurait trop le recommender.

Dans un autre registre, *Le passe-muraille* de Marcel Aymé est un recueil de courtes nouvelles. Il allie humour et simplicité, mais est un peu moins connu que *L’étranger* ou *Le petit prince*, et est tout de même un peu moins profond que ceux-ci.

Comment: Je pense que mon admiration pour le roman était attirée par sa portée philosophique car j’étais exposé à des idées de philo en lisant les œuvres de Cicérone en classe de latin et cela m’a beaucoup fait passionné de la littérature étrangère. Ainsi, j’ai acheté des œuvres de Jean-Paul Sartre, et je pense que je vais aimer ça.

Comment: @ThatLanguageGuy Jean-Paul Sartre m'a beaucoup intéressé quand nous l'avons abordé en philosophie. Je dois dire que je m'attendais à davantage, et que sa lecture après coup m'a un peu déçu. Je vous souhaite un contact plus agréable, ce qui est très possible, beaucoup de gens de ma famille et de mon cercle de connaissances l'aiment beaucoup.

Comment: Je vois. J’ai utilisé la méthode Assimil pour apprendre le français, et dans le deuxième tome on lisait des extraits du roman “à la recherche du temps perdu” et je voulais savoir si vous l’aviez lu ou si vous le recommanderiez ?

Comment: *À la recherche du temps perdu* n'est ni court, ni simple, et s'il est connu, c'est davantage par ouï-dire que par une réelle fréquentation de l'œuvre. Je ne l'ai pas lue, mais de ceux que je connais qui l'ont lue, il semble que ça polarise: on trouve que c'est d'une bouleversante beauté, ou au contraire d'un mortel ennui.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "like l'étranger".
If what you're looking for is a book with the "écriture blanche" writing style ("neutral" writing that doesn't show emotion in the main character or the narrator) then I'd suggest reading *La modification* by Butor which is written entirely in second person, or *l'amant* by Duras (didn't like this one but maybe you would).